# Merging Accounts

Tags: accounts

I noticed that there are a few seperate ubuntu accounts like one and software center. I'm not sure if there is another one for singing into this, but will they ever merge all of the accounts?

Comment: We don't have accounts here (we do, but the authentication just piggy-backs onto other account systems through OpenID).

Answer (score 1):

Work is underway to unify most of the Ubuntu services under the Ubuntu One login scheme at: https://login.ubuntu.com/ This is just an OpenID provider but the following services have been ported to use it (these are just some that I have used - there are certainly *many* more!):

```
https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/
https://forms.canonical.com/
http://ubuntuforums.org/
https://launchpad.net/
http://rt.ubuntu.com/
http://wiki.ubuntu.com/
https://software-center.ubuntu.com/
http://paste.ubuntu.com/
```

Ask Ubuntu allows any OpenID provided so you can add this to your account if you wish.